# Plot vertical surface below function

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I'm trying to create a very simple 3D plot using the [`rgl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) package: I have a function that just maps `x` values into `y` values. For a given `z` (in my example: `z = 1`), I can plot this function in a 3D plot:

```
library(rgl)

mycurve <- function(x) { return (1/x)}
myx <- seq(1, 10, by = 0.1)

plot3d(x = NA, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10), zlim = c(0, 5), 
       xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "height")
lines3d(x = myx, y = mycurve(myx), z = 1)
```

[image: 2D line in 3D plot]

However, even after hours of trying to understand the documentation of `?persp3d` and `?surface3d`, I still have no idea how to add a surface to my plot that "connects" my line to the x-y plane – like this:

[image: Space curve.]

(To generate this image, I cheated by plotting many lines: `for (i in seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)) { lines3d(x = myx, y = mycurve(myx), z = i) }`.)

I suppose that I need to supply the correct values to `surface3d` somehow. From `?surface3d`:

> The surface is defined by the matrix of height values in z, with rows corresponding to the values in x and columns corresponding to the values in y.

Given that my space curve is "vertical", each value of `x` corresponds to only 1 value of `y`. Still, I need to specify two `z` values for each `xy` pair, which is why I do not know how to proceed.

How can I plot a space curve as shown in the second image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `persp3d`, all 3 arguments can be matrices, so you can plot arbitrary surfaces.  For your needs, this works:

```
mycurve <- function(x) { return (1/x)}
myx <- seq(1, 10, by = 0.1)


xmat <- matrix(NA, 2, length(myx))
ymat <- matrix(NA, 2, length(myx))
zmat <- matrix(NA, 2, length(myx))
for (i in 0:1) { 
  xmat[i+1,] <- myx
  ymat[i+1,] <- mycurve(myx)
  zmat[i+1,] <- i
}
library(rgl)
persp3d(x = xmat, y = ymat, z = zmat, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10), zlim = c(0, 5), 
       xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "height", col = "gray")
```

The image produced looks like this:

[image]

If you want `z` to depend on `x` or `y`, you'll likely want a smaller step size, but this works for the surface you're after.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This shows exactly what I didn't understand: What matrices to use.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `persp3d` function one needs to create a matrix for z to correspond to all of the x and y values in the desired range.
I revised your function to take both the x and y parameters and return the desired z value.  The outer function will call the function repeatedly to fill the matrix.  Then plot, with the defined x and y axis and z (from the outer function)

```
library(rgl)

mycurve <- function(x, y) { return (1/x)}
myx <- seq(1, 10, by = 0.4)
myy <-seq(1, 10, by =0.4)
#create matrix
data<-outer(myx, myy, mycurve)
#plot points
persp3d(x=myx, y=myy, z=data, 
        xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "height")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, this plots the surface rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: @CL. The plot above is using x and y as the independent variables and z is the dependent variable, while your original plot y is the dependent variable.  Thus to rotate the plot, you'll need to change the axis labels to match your desired outcome.

Comment: Uhm, this is not really an option. In my actual usecase there are many other 2D and 3D elements in the plot and the line `mycurve` has to be in the `xy` plane.